# Passing parameters from android to AIR

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

I want to pass parameters from Android to AIR. I have read so many tutorials. But in one of the tutorial they have suggested that using intent is not a good option in this case to pass parameters.

They have suggested to use `this.dispatchStatusEventAsync("parameterName", Integer.toString(value));`.

I am using FlashRuntimeExtensions.jar as a library and using proper FREExtension, FREFunction and FREContext wherever necessary. But in main activity when i am calling ExtensionContext which is a class extending FREContext, I am getting an error of NoClassDefFoundError. I am trying other examples also but getting same error.

Can u please suggest me how can i do so or fix that error? Is there any other way to pass parameter from Android to AIR.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any suggestions please... its urgent!!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I simply meant how to pass parameters from Android app to AIR? Is there any other option than intent to send parameters??

Comment: I still don't get it.  I guess "Android App" helps a bit.  So, you have an app built in Java and deployed as a Native app?  And you want to send data from that app to app built with aIR and deployed as a native app.  Is that correct?  You're trying to share data between two Android then?

Comment: yes. You are correct. But i am not getting the thing that even if i am passing the data through intent then in AIR how do i retrieve their. B'z in AIR as per i know we can't use java code. So i got this context thing. but not able to use that properly